# Firebase custom claims as a list + security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am thinking of the following structure of security rules + custom claims:

```
auth.token.buckets = ['bucket1', 'bucket2', 'bucket3']
```

And the security rule like:

```
allow read if storage/{$bucket} is in auth.token.buckets
```

Is that possible? And if so, what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible indeed.

- The correct operator is `in`, since your token contains a [list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#list) of keys.
- The correct way to refer to the bucket is with `bucket`, without `$` or `{}`.

So the total rules could be something like:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{path=**} {
      allow read: if bucket in auth.token.buckets;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you'll have to store the full name of your bucket in the token, so something like `your-project-name.appspot.com`